# FadeinLeft Image scroll Waypoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have tried different websites even tried to decode waypoint guide but no luck. I can't seem to get scroll function to work with following code. (reference: http://blog.robamador.com/using-animate-css-jquery-waypoints/)

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
<!doctype html><html><head><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.1.0/animate.min.css">

<style>
img {
margin:1000px 0;
display:block;

}

</style>

<script>
//Animate from top
$('.animated').waypoint(function() {
$(this).toggleClass($(this).data('animated'));
},
{ offset: 'bottom-in-view' });
//Animate from bottom
 $('.animated').waypoint(function() {
 $(this).toggleClass($(this).data('animated'));});
 </script>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<img class="animated" data-animated="fadeInLeft" src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300">
<img class="animated" data-animated="bounce" src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/2.0.4/waypoints.min.js">   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, put the jQuery script and Waypoint script inclusion in the HEAD tag. This is, in the 99% of the case, the right way to include javascript libraries in your DOM.

Second thing: you write your javascript code in the HEAD tag (it's right), but without a "start control". In your case, the browser start to execute your javascript code before reading the rest of the DOM, so it can't attach events on the right elements (the images with class "animated") because it haven't read them yet. In simply word, when the browser start to read your SCRIPT tag, it don't know who ".animated" are, so it do nothing.

There are two way to resolve your problem:

1 - Move you SCRIPT tag and its content at the end of the BODY tag.

2 - Wrap you javascript code in a DOM.ready state like:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            //Animate from top
            $('.animated').waypoint(function() {
                $(this).toggleClass($(this).data('animated'));
            }, {
                offset : 'bottom-in-view'
            });

            //Animate from bottom
            $('.animated').waypoint(function() {
                $(this).toggleClass($(this).data('animated'));
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Honestly, I prefer the option number 2. =D